# Loop only through nested elements of the array item from D3 selectAll creation from data()

Tags: javascript, object, d3.js, nested

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm new to D3 and this has me incredibly frustrated.

Say I have a large nested JSON object I'm trying to visualize using D3. I'll use a simplified version as an example:

```
var dataArr = [
    {
        "name": "John",
        "stats":  [
            {
                "stat": "Weight",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "val": 190,
                        "week": 1,
                    },
                    {
                        "val": 170,
                        "week": 3,
                    }
            },
            {
                "stat": "Waist",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "val": 40,
                        "week": 1,
                    },
                    {
                        "val": 36,
                        "week": 3,
                    }
            }
    },
    {
        "name": "Fred",
        "stats":  [
            {
                "stat": "Weight",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "val": 230,
                        "week": 1,
                    },
                    {
                        "val": 200,
                        "week": 3,
                    }
            },
            {
                "stat": "Waist",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "val": 44,
                        "week": 1,
                    },
                    {
                        "val": 38,
                        "week": 3,
                    }
            }
    }
];
```

If I use the following to create divs based on `dataArr`:

```
var divs = d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
        .data(dataArr)
        .enter()
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "outerDiv");
```

That will give me two divs, one for John and one for Fred. Where I'm running into trouble is I want to create a two divs (one for Weight and one for Waist) inside of each outer div, and want to access ONLY the nested data under John in John's div and under Fred in Fred's div. I'm certain D3 allows for this, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this especially when dealing with data that's both nested JSON objects and arrays which makes indexes difficult.

I'd be so appreciative if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep the parent in variable and iterate over them to prepare nested data as

```
   var divs = d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
    .data(dataArr)
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "outerDiv");


   var innerdiv = divs.selectAll("div")
   .data(function(d){console.log(d); return d.stats}) //passing nested data
   .enter()
   .append("div")
   .attr("class","innerdiv")
```

Sample fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/9666/

Comment: Thanks for the response. How does this work if I'm appending divs to outerDiv for stylistic purposes before appending divs for data purposes? I can't figure out how to keep passing data down to children of children of outerDiv for use later, as .data(function(d){return d}) doesn't seem to be allowed

Comment: append works only after data & enter if array else it will append single div moreover the variables divs,innerdiv can always be accessed you want to preserver parent data in children's at 1st level and so on right ?